# How to create multi level random nested list in python based on user input on no of levels

Tags: python

I am looking for a function which can create random multi level nested list in python.
Lets say if a level is 2, it should create list of lists.
Similarly if user provide paramter 3, it should create list of (list of lists). For example: 3 level should look like

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],  [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
```

The level can vary based on user input.
Creating two level random list is straightforward using below logic but when the level is more than 2, I cant thing of generic logic.

```
multlist = [[random.randint(1, 1024) for columns in range(4)] for rows in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the exact same method and make it a recursive function (so call your own function instead of the inner list comprehension if n > 1). For example:

```
import random

def make_list(depth):
    if depth == 1:
        return [random.randint(1, 1024) for columns in range(4)]
    else:
        return [make_list(depth - 1) for rows in range(3)]

print(make_list(1))
print(make_list(2))
print(make_list(3))
```